# Laptop Memory suddenly peaking

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory

We have a Toshiba Laptop that has suddenly begun to run at maximum memory capacity.

Specs (Going off the top of my head)

- OS: Windows 7 Professional
- RAM: 4 GB
- 32 bit OS

We have done nothing out of the ordinary, have not installed any new software (or removed anything), no updates, no new processes, nothing.

This started occurring when a user was attempting to print to PDF using the Adobe PDF Writer. All that was open was the Task manager (to monitor the PC from previous performance issues), and Windows Explorer.

- We had a look through `msconfig`, nothing out of the ordinary, maximum amount of memory was around 2,000 K for startup processes.
- All large tasks (system scans, defrags etc) were all scheduled after hours.
- Stack traces revealed nothing out of the ordinary.
- Memory test revealed nothing out of the ordinary.

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?

Comment: Check in Task Manager to see What process(es) are using the most memory.

Comment: @RsyaStudios from what I have been able to discern, Windows Explorer sitting at around 2000 k. When it's running at such a high memory level it's almost impossible to do anything. It takes 15 minutes to switch tabs in the Task manager

Comment: What is everything else running at? 2000k is hardly anything. Are you missing some 0s?

Comment: @ekaj Negative. 2000 k was the biggest.

Comment: have you disabled the pagefile? If you can't switch between tasks, how did you know that the memory is the cause?

Comment: @magicandre1981 In one attempt to see what was going on I had the performance tab open first, it was running at 3.98 GB memory, then after about 20 minutes of idling it bottomed out to about .3GB, then rose steadily and coasted again at 1.9 GB. Left it like that for 30 mins, then attempted to restart the task and it immediately peaked again.

Comment: run this in background: http://pastebin.com/peqLGxSa when the PC gets responsive again after the issue, to to the CMD and stop the trace. zip ad upload the large ETL file.